# Centos Web server can not connect to my computer's ip on port 9001

Tags: centos, windows-7

When i use;

```
nc -v 151.XXX.240.227 9001
```

on my Centos server, i get

```
nc: connect to 151.XXX.240.227 port 9001 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out
```

In my Windows 7 computer, Tcpview shows that port 9001 is listening, i also forwarded port 9001 from my router.

How can i debug this connection problem?

Thanks

EDIT

The problem was with the router port forwarding, in port forwarding i was using my own ip as client, changing it to ipv4 that i found with ipconfig command in cmd solved the problem.

Comment: Is your port opened 9001?

Comment: I think so, how can i be sure? I also tried with canyouseeme.org and it also cant connect to my ip on port 9001. It says Error: I could not see your service on 151.2XX.240.227 on port (9001) Reason: Connection timed out

Comment: On your windows box check firewall and make sure you have opened port 9001 in outbound and inbound.

Comment: Thats what i am asking here hoping to get help how to do it.

Comment: CentOS has quite restrictive default iptables ruleset. Try turn off iptables and check whether it helps.

Comment: even other services cant connect to my pc (like canyouseeme.org) so it seems problem is in my windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to open both Windows Firewall incoming 9001, and iptables outbound 9001.

**Linux**

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 151.XXX.240.227 --dport 9001 -j ACCEPT
```

**Windows**

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 9001" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=9001
```

Comment: I runned first command in server and I runned 2. command in windows cmd and it answered : Ok but still i get Connection timed out error

Comment: still i get Connection timed out error from nc command but in canyouseeme.org the error changed from connection timed out to Error: I could not see your service on 151.250.235.47 on port (9001)
Reason: Connection refused , in tcpview it shows phpstorm is listening on port 9001 which is correct

Comment: Do you have the ports opened on your router also?